# Preventing my own app name from ActivityViewController using Shared Extension inside my own app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using Shared Extension for importing documents into my application. I am using activityview controller for exporting my documents to other applications. But i am able to see my own app name in activityviewontroller inside my app in ios11.
Please help.

Comment: Found any solution to this ?